# Getting count of every word in the list by seperating

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have the following list and want to get the count of each word

```
t_series=['Chinese, Italian, Fast Food',
     'North Indian, Chinese, South Indian, Fast Food, Biryani, Street Food, Beverages',
     'South Indian, North Indian, Chinese, Biryani, Street Food, Sandwich, Beverages',
     'Bakery, Fast Food',
     'Fast Food, Italian, Chinese, Rolls, Sandwich',
     'Mithai, Street Food, Fast Food, Beverages',
     'South Indian, Chinese, Street Food, Fast Food, Desserts, Beverages',
     'North Indian, Chinese, South Indian, Fast Food, Desserts, Beverages',
     'Fast Food, Italian, Chinese, Rolls, Sandwich',
     'North Indian, South Indian',]
```

After spliting the string string as:-

```
list_sep = [st for row in t_series for st in row]
```

I am getting the output as:-

['C',
 'h',
 'i',
 'n',
 'e',
 's',
 'e',
 ',',
 ' ',
 'I',
 't',
 'a',
 'l',
 'i',
 'a',
 'n',
 ',',] and so on.

I want output as:-
[Chinese,
 Italian,
 Fast Food,
 South Indian] and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` by `,`:

```
list_sep = [st for row in t_series for st in row.split(', ')]
print (list_sep)
['Chinese', 'Italian', 'Fast Food', 'North Indian', 'Chinese', 'South Indian', 
 'Fast Food', 'Biryani', 'Street Food', 'Beverages', 'South Indian', 'North Indian',
 'Chinese', 'Biryani', 'Street Food', 'Sandwich', 'Beverages', 'Bakery', 'Fast Food', 
 'Fast Food', 'Italian', 'Chinese', 'Rolls', 'Sandwich', 'Mithai', 'Street Food', 
 'Fast Food', 'Beverages', 'South Indian', 'Chinese', 'Street Food', 'Fast Food',
 'Desserts', 'Beverages', 'North Indian', 'Chinese', 'South Indian', 'Fast Food', 
 'Desserts', 'Beverages', 'Fast Food', 'Italian', 'Chinese', 'Rolls', 'Sandwich', 
 'North Indian', 'South Indian']
```